the non abstract class custom react is missing implementations error coming all the time why?
lib/main.dart:608:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'CustomRect' is missing implementations for these members:

Rect.x
Rect.y
Try to either
provide an implementation,
inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
mark the class as abstract, or
provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class CustomRect implements Rect {
^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/quadtree_dart-1.1.1/lib/src/rect.dart:11:10: Context: 'Rect.x' is defined here.
double x;
^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/quadtree_dart-1.1.1/lib/src/rect.dart:12:10: Context: 'Rect.y' is defined here.
double y;
^
Target kernel_snapshot failed:
